# Javascript old syntax to arrow function conversion

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, arrow-functions

So I want to use this example without jquery or other libraries.

I have this code

```
let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {...}
```

As you can see it uses the old style `function()`

How do I change this to an arrow function style one?

```
let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = () => {...}
```

This doesn't work.
Am I close or am I looking at this completely wrong? Again I don't want to use libraries for this exercise.

Comment: This does work. The error is somewhere else

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? The browser isn't supporting it? You could also use `const` instead of `let` I doubt you're re-assigning `xmlHttp`

Comment: snippet is working in chrome v59 . what browser are you on. might be browser not supporting arrow functions yet and might need a polyfill

I tried :

let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = () => {console.log('s')}

Comment: Well that is what I thought, but if I use the arrow function the browser console does not return anything - the old style function does work

Comment: You're probably trying to use `this` inside the function that works differently with arrow functions. Nothing is wrong with the assignment.

Comment: I am using Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) - will try some of the suggestions above

Comment: @DarthJDG your comments was the ticket - I changed `this` to `xmlHttp` which is the variable name and it worked. I will read up on the `this` part of the arrow function :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with arrow functions is that they keep the `this` object of the outer scope.

Your first example would have the `XMLHttpRequest` bound to the `this` reference the second the `window`

To make this work with arrow notation, you need to reference the `XMLHttpRequest` with the outer name `xmlHttp` or bind it to the callback function:

```
let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = ((request) => {...}).bind(undefined, request);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Be aware that you can not override the `this` reference of arrow functions by any mean (bind, call, apply)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - will accept the answer when it allows me to

Answer (score 1):

Bellian's code above looks nice but the `.bind(undefined, request);` gives the simplicity away.

There's an alternate way of doing this in such a way that it would sync to your questions expected answer:

I highly recommend you should do this instead. The arrow function removed the direct `this` to gain better access to the results. Check for yourself `console.log(x)` only without the `.target`

You can also:

```html
let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = x => {
  let result = x.target;

        if(result.readyState == 4 && result.status == 200){         
            console.log(result.responseText);
            
        }
    
};
```