# Issue with POST Request in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The button click is working, as I can see the log but the POST request doesn't happen.
I've made a simple input box, and when the button is clicked, it should send a POST request to the server.

I can't figure out why the POST request never takes place, so please help me figure it out.

Comment.js:

```
import React from 'react';

export class Comment extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  
    }


    handleClick() {
        //SEND POST request
        console.log('handling click');
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/comments"
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
              console.log('POST request sent, comment posted.')
            }
        xhr.open('POST',URL);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
        xhr.send(document.getElementById('comment-box').value);
        }

    }


    
    render(){
        const comment_form = (
           <div className="posts">
              <input type="text" id="comment-box" name="comment" placeholder="Say something nice." />
              <button className="submit-button" type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}> Comment </button>
           </div>
        );
        return comment_form;
    }
}
```

Comment: why aren't you using `fetch` ?

Comment: What does `document.getElementById('comment-box').value` returns?

Comment: @Asutosh as far as I know, it returns the text entered in input text.

Comment: I see, added the answer. It was just a syntax mistake. Post request works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a syntax mistake such as closing } of onReadyState eventhandler was not right place

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export class Comment extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    //SEND POST request
    console.log("handling click");
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/comments";
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        console.log("POST request sent, comment posted.");
      }
    };
    xhr.open("POST", URL);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
    console.log(document.getElementById("comment-box").value);
    xhr.send(document.getElementById("comment-box").value);
  }

  render() {
    const comment_form = ( <
      div className = "posts" >
      <
      input type = "text"
      id = "comment-box"
      name = "comment"
      placeholder = "Say something nice." /
      >
      <
      button className = "submit-button"
      type = "button"
      onClick = {
        this.handleClick
      } >
      {
        " "
      }
      Comment {
        " "
      } <
      /button> <
      /div>
    );
    return comment_form;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

Arrow function bind `this` and onreadystatechange callback is called when `this === Comment`. So xhr.onreadystatechange not working.

```js
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
              console.log('POST request sent, comment posted.')
            }
```

I think below reference is helpful to you. It is not problem from react but from arrow function.
This reference is more clearly write about that problem.

### Reference

1. [Javascript old syntax to arrow function conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45299584/javascript-old-syntax-to-arrow-function-conversion)